# What is the difference between container instances pulling from dockerhub.com and microsoft.com

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to know the exact difference between pulling the docker form dockerhub.com and microsoft.com

any idea?
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Have you tried pulling the same image from both and comparing them with `docker inspect`?

Comment: What image? This is a bit like asking the difference between downloading a file from different servers, the answer could be "it's the same thing, just on a different server".

Answer (score 0):

## Location

The location is important and it can speed up (or down) things.
For you, it doesn't make a big difference. You have always to download the images via internet and this can be slow.
But if you're using azure, then there can be a difference.

[image: Locations]

As you can see in the image, it is possible that Microsofts Container-Engine don't have to download the images via internet. It can fetch them from "a closer location".

## Data

I guess, that Microsoft Registry is just a mirror of DockerHub. That means, the images **should** be the same. You can verify this, when you pull the image from both locations and compare them. Make a `docker pull` for each registries and compare the result, see below for an example.

```bash
$ docker pull microsoft-server/alpine
<layer-hash>
<layer-hash>
<layer-hash>

$ docker pull hub.docker.com/alpine
<layer-hash>
<layer-hash>
<layer-hash>
```

And now, you can compare all hashes.